# How to find all router contract addresses

Tags: router

I would like to get all router contract adresses deployed on ETH and BSC?  Is there a way search for contract or anotherway?

Comment: What do you mean by router?

Comment: Routers like PancakeSwap: Router v2 (0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E)

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't found a way, perhaps looking contracts with calls to `addLiquidity`, `removeLiquidity`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I did it the way you said before, just would like know if there is easiest way to do.